# Knowledge With redirect and structure of url

Tags: .htaccess, url

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^byer=([^&]+)$
    RewriteRule ^reparator-byer$ /iphone-reparation-%1? [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^iphone-reparation-(.+)$ /reparator-byer?byer=$1 [L]
    ErrorDocument 404 https://mobilecare.dk/404/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ https://mobilecare.dk [L,R=301]
    Redirect 301 /resultat?store=4UPhones&type=3 https://mobilecare.dk
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hello i have a annoying problem.
im looking to make a domain url more seo friendly and found that i can do this in .htaccess. However the redirect does not work and other pages thats not even with the same string are affected after i use the code below

My goal is to get

https://mobilecare.dk/reparator-byer?byer=Odense

to

https://mobilecare.dk/iphone-reparation-odense

Comment: You created a rewrite loop. Keep in mind that the `L` flag the your `RewriteRule` you added only terminates the current run of the rewriting engine. That means that your request will get redirected in the next run by the rule one above the new one. Have a try using the `END` flag instead of the `L` flag. Take a look at the documentation about their exact meaning: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule